# What is the recommended headphone hardware spec to pair with Apple Watch Series 2?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, apple-watch

Does Apple Watch Series 2 support all bluetooth headphones, or do I need to check for specific bluetooth requirements before buying?

Most of the sites suggest Beats Jaybird. Will the watch not work with common bluetooth headphones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a [support article](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP746?locale=en_US) from Apple the Apple Watch Series 2 has a Bluetooth 4.0 chip. So common bluetooth headphones should also work with the Watch.

Answer (score 0):

I Had been having a ton of issues trying to get my Apple Watch Series 2 to recognize the Bluetooth headset saying unable to pair make sure it's on pairing mode and try again.

I finally figured it out. Here's how to get it to connect.

- First turn off the Apple Watch
- Now turn it back on
- Get the Bluetooth headset in pairing mode again
- Open Bluetooth settings on the Watch
- Touch to pair

For me it connected like a charm using this process!